# Listen to Http server-side Request (document type) Events via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, httprequest

I am trying to show a gif or message at the moment user click on the link or change URL to send a request to server-side (no ajax call). My reason is: some pages take some seconds to be processed and it would be better user see a loading message while the request is processing.

I tried to listen to server-side events. I checked chrome how it works and captures this kind of requests.
chrome differentiate these types of requests with others base on the document type.

[image]

My exact question is: How can I capture/listen to the HTTP request with document type via Javascript at the moment of sending the request to server?

Comment: Bit of a chicken and egg problem here, if your first page your loading is blocked, you have no way of doing anything in Javascript,..  ` (no ajax call).`  That's pretty much your only option, that or `fetch` from the calling side.   There is another option, but can be hit or miss, in theory you can partially send a HTML page, but this is something your back end needs to be able to do, and if it's something reverse-proxy's etc can cope with is another issue.

Comment: I am looking for browser API (it is already in browser) or something to get request and check them base on the document type. Dose browser or properly javascript provide such this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with using window.onbeforeunload() function. this event rise whenever any refresh or load happens.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
        console.log("onbeforeunload Call listen to refresh event on _layout page.")
        ShowWaiting(true);
    }
```